# Comparing German string in PHP file

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I have code like this:

```
$rowTitle = trim($row->children(0)->plaintext);
echo $rowTitle;
if (strcmp($rowTitle, 'Bügellänge in mm') == 0) {
    echo 4;
}
```

`rowTitle` is from another German site, but
I copied from `rowTitle` from this `echo $rowTitle`, when I run code and paste it in `if` statement and after that `strcmp` doesn't return `0`.

Is the problem in my file and editor or where is it ? It is `UTF-8`.

Comment: What is `var_dump($rowTitle)` returning?

Comment: Check the encoding of the german site.

Comment: It returns `string(18) "Bügellänge in mm"`. From meta tag in their site - `text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Strange I get `4`/`0`. https://3v4l.org/ScUVE

Comment: Yes, when I add both strings I get 4, but same text from another site `string(18) "Bügellänge in mm"` with text hardcoded in the file aren't equal.

Comment: If I close and open program with same file I see this `if (strcmp($rowTitle, 'B?gell?nge in mm') == 0) {` . i am using `SublimeText` and `PHPStorm`.